# Debugging between c++ and c# code in WSL2 (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, c++, .net, visual-studio, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Here is the project setup:

This project is being built on WSL2 and I am using a template from https://github.com/roozbehid/dotnet-vcxproj
to build both the c++ shared library and the c# program file.

There is a c++ source file that has one function (just a test function that returns an integer). This file is what is used to build a shared library(.so file)

Test.cpp:

```
extern "C" {
  int test( int x ) {
      return x + 26;
  }
}
```

Note that when the shared library is created, the final file is named libTest.so (This is due to some settings in Visual Studio)

And the program file:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

internal class Hello
{
    [DllImport("libTest.so", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint = "test")]
    public static extern int test(int x);
    public static void Main()
    {
        int a = test(52);
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, World." + "\n We passed in the number: " + 52 + "\n What's the magic number? \n" + a + "!!");
    }
}
```

Now when I set a breakpoint at the line

```
int a = test(52);
```

where the function from the shared library is called, Visual Studio simply steps over that line and doesn't go into the Test.cpp file where the function is defined.

I am not sure how I can get this debugger to work so that I can step between C# and C++ code. I know this works on Windows using a similar P/Invoke feature, but since this is on a WSL it might not be working as expected.

If anyone has encountered and solved this issue before, I'd really appreciate your input on it.

P.S. I saw this post (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/net-core-c-mixed-mode-debugging-with-wsl2/1586601) on the Visual Studio Developer Community forum asking for this feature to be implemented, so I'm not sure if this is even possible at the moment, but if someone knows a workaround that would really help. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try setting a breakpoint in your C++ code?

Comment: Yes, I've tried setting breakpoints all across, messing around with settings but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from [.NET Core Debugging with WSL 2 - Preview](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.Dot-Net-Core-Debugging-With-Wsl2&ssr=false#qna):

> This is not currently on our roadmap, but it's something we'll
> continue to evaluate for the future.

Comment: Hi, @arifislam May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer?